# Does getline() not extract the delimiter?

Tags: c++, getline

So I was taking input some integers and then taking input some sentences.

This code works fine:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
main(){
    int c,b,n,i;string s;
    cin>>n>>b>>c;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>ws;
        getline(cin,s,'\n');
        cout<<s; 
     }
    }
```

Example:

```
3 3 3
This is weird
This is weirdDefinitely makes
Definitely makesNo sense
No sense
```

However, when I try to omit the cin>>ws inside the forloop, it doesn't work properly, eg this code segment,

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
main(){
    int c,b,n,i;string s;
    cin>>n>>b>>c;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            getline(cin,s,'\n');
            cout<<s;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
3 3 3
This is weird
This is weirdDefinitely makes
Definitely makes
```

..and terminates there instead of taking all three inputs.
Why is that? cin>>ws extracts all whitespace from the input but isn't getline() doing that too? So why does it not work properly when I omit cin>>ws in the forloop?

Comment: What is the actual problem: in what way does the code with uses of `std::ws` not work as expected?

Comment: Are you redirecting input from a file or actually typing at the console?

Comment: @DietmarKühl the problem is if I omit cin>>ws inside the forloop, it doesn't take input properly, why is that?

Comment: @MarkRansom typing in the console

Comment: What does "it doesn't take input properly" mean? Ideally, provide input and expected output or, even better, demo the problem using a `std::istringstream`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl done, thanks.

Comment: You made a change to the code as well as adding the examples; that change was critical. Next time *please* post your exact code!

Comment: Your first visible output is the second input. See [Why does `std::getline()` skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: @Little_idiot: I have updated my answer to explain what's going on.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sorry, will keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

`std::getline()` extract characters until it extracted the first delimiter character (by default '\n'). The delimiter is not stored in the result but it is extracted. It does *not* extract whitespace in general or multiple delimiter characters.

As an aside: *always* check whether input works *after* trying to read a value.

In the example printed, the issue is is that after formatted input, i.e., using the `>>` operator, whitespaces are not extracted. That is, the first calls to `std::getline()` extracts the empty string terminated by the initial newline. It generally *is* necessary to extract trailing whitespace when switching between formatted and unformatted I/O. That is, You'd want code like

```
if (cin>>n>>b>>c >> std::ws) {
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if (getline(cin,s,'\n')) {
            cout << "i=" << i << ":'" << s << "'\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I can't recommend input operations without adding check for success. The output is changed to make it more easily visible what is going on: try the code with/without this particular `std::endl` to see what is happening.

Comment: Clears it up. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

The default delimiter for getline() is '\n', so there is no need to include that in the getline call, though, it should not change the functionality.

See for example [Same as getline(input, str, input.widen('\n')), that is, the default delimiter is the endline character.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

The change in formatting from the integer input to the getline() input leaves some whitespace (endl) after the integer as explained by @DietmarKühl.

You can change the getline() call to eliminate the delimiter to

`getline(cin,s);`

which will cause getline() to use '\n' as the default delimiter.

I have modified the 'n' variable to count and removed the other integers to make the code a little simpler to read:

```c++
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i;  // index
    int count;  // number of strings to accept
    std::string str;

    std::cout << "Input the number of strings you would like me to process: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> count;

    if (std::cin >> count >> std::ws) {
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (getline(std::cin, str)) {
                std::cout << "i=" << i << ":'" << str << "'\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is actually incorrect: `getline()` has two reason to stop: either the delimiter is found or the end of the stream is found. It doesn't stop on newline if it isn't the used delimiter.

Comment: Changed, same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Cin doesn't extract all white spaces, it just gets the first word until the first white space. It is like having a getline with a space delimiter(not quite but close to).

Getline takes the whole line and has the default '\n' delimiter like mentioned above.

Ex:

```
string a = "Stack Overflow is awesome";
```

can give you Stack and getline will give you everything at that line

Comment: Re: " cin just extracts the word" -- `std::cin` doesn't extract anything. `>>` and `getline` extract characters from an input stream; when you pass `std::cin` to those functions they extract characters from it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `cin >>` it doesn't remove any whitespace after the input. This means the newline that terminated the first 3 inputs is still in the buffer, waiting to be read by the first `getline`. Since there's nothing before the newline, the first `getline` delivered an empty string. Your output should have included a newline so you could have seen the empty line, then it would have made sense.

Originally the code you posted showed a `cin >> ws` just before the `for` loop which would have eliminated this problem.